# How do I update Custom Label's value using apex? Which one would be a better option metadata api or tooling api? Please provide example

Tags: metadata-api, tooling-api

I'am working on post deployment automation process in salesforce. I am stuck on how should I update values in custom labels which needs tobe updated manually after a sandbox refresh.

Comment: Why closed? A concrete answer can be given that objectively answers the question.

Comment: A question with 7 upvotes and a concrete answer gets closed :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [this MetadataService class](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi/blob/master/apex-mdapi/src/classes/MetadataService.cls) and follow [this example](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi/blob/master/apex-mdapi/src/classes/MetadataServiceExamples.cls#L140):

```
public static void updateField()
{
    MetadataService.MetadataPort service = createService();
    MetadataService.CustomField customField = new MetadataService.CustomField();
    customField.fullName = 'Test__c.TestField__c';
    customField.label='New Test Field Label';
    customField.type_x = 'Text';
    customField.length = 52;
    List<MetadataService.SaveResult> results =
        service.updateMetadata(
            new MetadataService.Metadata[] { customField });
    handleSaveResults(results[0]);
}
```

In your case, you will probably want to use only the `fullName` and `label` attributes. Type and length are not relevant for you to set here.

More on how to handle the save results can be viewed in the example class at line 1536.

Comment: To use this code you will need to setup https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi to make external HTTP calls to the Metadata SOAP Api